Оставить знак препинания нетронутым
Задание: Переместите первую букву каждого слова в конец, затем добавьте "ay" в конец слова. Оставьте знаки препинания нетронутыми.
Это мой код! Он работает, однако я не могу оставить знаки препинания нетронутыми, как это сделать. Желательно не сильно меняя исходный код.
function pigIt(str){
  return str.split(" ").map( (a) => a.slice(1) + a[0] + 'ay').join(' ')
}

Пример работы кода:
pigIt('Pig latin is cool'); // igPay atinlay siay oolcay
pigIt('Hello world !');     // elloHay orldway !
То есть, если в предложении нету знаков препинания, то мой код работает, но как учесть знаки препинания?

Вы не приняли ни одного ответа на свои вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer


\p{L} - совпадает с буквами на любых языках;
(\p{L}) - группа (первая) с первой буквой слова;
(\p{L}*) - группа (вторая) с остальными буквами слова;
g - флаг, который заставляет редактировать все слова. Без него замена будет сделана только раз;
u - флаг обработки Unicode, без него выражение \p{L} не работает;
$2 - вставляет вторую группу - хвост слова;
$1 - вставляет первую группу - первую букву слова.

const pigIt = s => s.replace(/(\p{L})(\p{L}*)/gu, '$2$1ay');

